# document.execCommand for Headings in iOS webView

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, uiwebview, xcode4.3

I am implementing a rich text editor in a webView (contentEditable set to true). To stylize the text I am using following command:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.execCommand(\"PLACEHOLDER\")"];
```

where PLACEHOLDER can be Bold, Italic, Underline etc.
The problem is I want to implement headings as well but they are not working this way. Maybe the webView doesn't support headings. I don't know exactly. How can I incorporate headings control in my rich text editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out a way around for that. I hope it would be helpful for someone like me. The correct code for that is :

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'h1')"];
```